# SearchComplete with Vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

> SearchComplete breaks the expected functionality of `{c|d|y}/pattern`, effectively reducing them to `/pattern`.
>
> SearchComplete breaks use of `/<Up>` to search history on some systems - it seems like it is specifically a problem in non-gui vim compiled as 64bit displayed within a terminal emulator. This problem results in typing `/ switching to Insert mode and inserting the letter 'A' on a new line, instead of searching the history. I tried to figure out the bug, but I couldn't. Removing SearchComplete fixes the problem.

This is an excerpt I saw from http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Script:474.

I was wondering if there is a workaround for this problem. Because both of these features ar so useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last update of that plugin is from 2002; it's probably unmaintained if the author didn't respond to the feedback on the Vim Tips Wiki page.

You can try the alternative [CmdlineComplete - complete command-line (: / etc.)](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2222) plugin; this works well for me.

Comment: CmdlineComple is useful! There some plugin that satisfy my old request (tab autocompletion in search mode), see: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11974/autocompletion-in-command-line-search